# How to look for more than one element in an embedded array in MongoDb

Tags: sql, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a `mongodb` query: (Give me settings where account='test')

```
db.collection_name.find({"account" : "test1"}, {settings : 1}).pretty();
```

where I get the following output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("49830ede4bz08bc0b495f123"),
    "settings" : {
        "clusterData" : {
            "us-south-1" : "cluster1",
            "us-east-1" : "cluster2"
        },
    },
```

What I'm looking for now, is to give me the `account` where the `clusterData` **has more than 1 element in its array**.

I'm only interested in listing those accounts with (2) or more elements.

I've tried this:

```
db.collection_name.find({'settings.clusterData.1': {$exists: true}}, {account : 1}).pretty();
```

Its not returning any results. Is my query correct? Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it isn't working is that your `clusterdata` is an object, not an array. I would suggest changing your data to be an array of clusters with two properties like below, then it will work.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("49830ede4bz08bc0b495f123"),
    "settings" : {
        "clusterData" : [
            {
                name : "cluster1",
                location : "us-south-1"
            },
            {
                name : "cluster2",
                location : "us-east-1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your input. However, I don't have the option to change this to an array. I'm given the data as an object. Thanks.

Comment: @noober Then I don't think what you are asking is possible.Your options are get the document and count the keys, modify the document to be an array, modify the document to store the number of keys or query the existence of the keys by their name.